# when I use shopee open platform API,I use the follow method to build a url to send a post request,I often get the message "Wrong sign",any solutions?

Tags: java, biginteger

```
public static String buildSignAndUrl(long partnerId, String secret, String path){
            long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
            String base_String = String.format("%s%s%s", partnerId, path, timestamp);
            byte[] baseStringBytes;
            byte[] partner_key;
            BigInteger sign = null;
            try{
                baseStringBytes = base_String.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                partner_key = secret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HmacAlgorithms.HMAC_SHA_256.toString());
                SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(partner_key, HmacAlgorithms.HMAC_SHA_256.toString());
                mac.init(secret_key);
                sign = new BigInteger(mac.doFinal(baseStringBytes));
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String url = SANDBOX_HOST + path + String.format("?partner_id=%s&timestamp=%s&sign=%s",
                    partnerId, timestamp, String.format("%032x", sign));
            return url;
        }
```

// Why use this url to send a post may cause "Wrong sign"? the timestamp in url and the timestamp to calculate a sign are same;

Comment: `sign = new BigInteger(mac.doFinal(baseStringBytes));` this will be a negative integer about half the time. You need to use the [sign-magnitude constructer for BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,byte%5B%5D)).

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk thank you,and I want to ask another question,Why the method 'String.format(%032x, sign) ' may return a String of length 63?

Comment: The 32 in `%032x` is the **minimum** width. If the result needs more than 32 characters then it is expanded. HMAC-sha-256 produces a 32 *byte* result, which requires 64 hex characters to represent.  You should use `String.format(%064x, sign)`

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk thank you very much indeed